# Семантическая ошибка в python я не могу её исправить

Tags: python

Я хочу вывести на экран Меня зовут Name ,  а мой возраст age  я присвоил переменным значения , но пайтон выводит не значения переменных name и age , а просто name age

Я долго уже пытаюсь это исправить , но ничего  не помогает помогите пожалуйста

```
Name = "..."
Age = 111
print("Меня зовут Name , a мой возраст - Age")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

либо печатайте их отдельно:

```
print("Меня зовут", Name, ", a мой возраст -", Age)
```

либо используйте `f`-строки (python3.6+)

```
print(f"Меня зовут {Name}, a мой возраст - {Age}")
```

Comment: Но появляется ошибка unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'set' знаете как её исправить

Comment: @Kolya странно... у меня такой ошибки нет. скорее всего при копирование вы где то допустили ошибку

Comment: Хорошо спасибо большое

Comment: @Kolya https://qna.habr.com/q/1264482 , ошибка где-то в другом месте кода